# Paypal IPN vs webhook events

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-webhooks

our platform has defined IPN for mass payouts and it's defined couple of years ago (it wasn't deprecated at that time). Now, we have started with new payout using new RestAPI and webhooks and for the new implementation with defined webhooks events only for payout.

QUESTION?
Is there are any conflicts between webhooks and IPN. Can it happen that payout (trigger by new RestAPI) trigger IP?

KR,
Milos

Comment: The only conflict would arise in your callback hook(s) if they're using the same URL and path. I would just define a new hook file name for your RestAPI webhook callback or simply disable IPN if your sure that it's not being used anymore.